# ORM for dynamic tables in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, orm

I am using a SQL Server database, in my C# application the schema of the table in the DB changes at runtime. I am looking forward to use any ORM Tool which can work with the above mentioned scenario. Pls help me out.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model

Answer (score 2):

If you are using NHibernate, please check ['dynamic-component' mapping](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/11/nhibernate-mapping-ltdynamic-componentgt.aspx). It allows you to map columns in a dictionary. That way the schema may be altered without recompiling the application. (NHibernate session factory needs to be recreated in your program after altering the mapping if the changes needs to be visible without application restart.)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you needing to modify the schema at runtime exactly? Depending on what you're trying to do a better solution might be to redesign your schema so no runtime changes are needed. If the schema is changing a lot at runtime, performance will become fairly horrible once you get to a large number of rows.

Comment: why exactly should the perfomance decrease if the schema changes? typically the performance decreases if you make a EAV model on sql server and fill it with a large number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

if you expect a small number of rows / database size go with the mentioned wiki-link and use a EAV model.

if you eg. store 4mio persons don't go with it. :) instead modify the database-schema at runtime. we use subsonic 2.2 and extended it in our core to allow some of the table-schema changes during runtime.